# How to read inputs separated by spaces in python, as different data types dynamically preferably onto a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

Is there a way to insert **first** input as **str** the **next** input as **int** and the **next** as **float** onto a list. Assuming the three inputs are separated by spaces are taken as input.

```
data = map(str,int,float,input.split()) # Something like this, I know the syntax here is wrong
```

Comment: Actually it is a funny problem, where did it come from? If it is your homework, shouldn't you put some effort of your own into solving it?

Comment: Err.. :) nope just something that popped up on my mind...I have this weird way of asking questions though maybe because of doing too much of homeworks, Lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply:

```
task = input().split()
task[1] = int(task[1])
task[2] = float(task[2])
```

or in a more convoluted way:

```
task = [ f(x) for (f, x) in zip([str, int, float], input().split()) ]
```

Comment: Yup, the second model was something I was looking after, thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can do this. Try this:

```
>>> task = input().split()
hello 3 42.3
>>> task       # task is a list of strings
['hello', '3', '42.3']

# get the 3 parts of task

>>> string = task[0]
>>> int = int(task[1])
>>> float = float(task[2])
>>> string, int, float
('hello', 3, 42.3)
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but I'm asking if there is a method that dynamically converts the input to a particular type and inserts it onto a list as it fetches the input.

Comment: No, there isn't. You could make your own.

Comment: Look at @Błotosmętek's answer though, it's more concise than mine.

Comment: Thanks alot Noah :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't some already available way to do it but you can write your own function for it; such as this:

```py
def my_input(data_types):
    user_input = input()
    split_user_input = user_input.split()
    converted_input_tokens = []

    for input_token, data_type in zip(split_user_input, data_types):
        converted_input_tokens.append(data_type(input_token))

    return converted_input_tokens
```

It will do exactly(no more, no less) what you showed in the example you gave. You can use it this way:

```py
>>> my_input((str, int, float))
1 2 3
```

Which will return:

```
['1', 2, 3.0]
```

It can be made much more generic, of course. For example, you could add arguments for the input prompt, the `sep` and `maxsplit` for the `str.split` method used in the function, etc.

If you are in doubt about how to do that, have a look at the official documentation for `input`, `str.split` and also do some research on type-conversions in Python.

Comment: Thanks alot, for your effort :)

Answer (score -1):

you can explicitly  define each input as particular type.